# Angular mat-label disappears when mat-select form-field is on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

New to Angular and have been reading the Material documentation on mat-form-fields.  I am having a weird bug happening when the form-field is focused.  My mat-label disappears on focus and reappears once focus is lost.

*This only appears to be happening in Chrome.  Firefox and Edge do not have this bug*

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Days</mat-label>
    <mat-select value="{{pD.Days[0]}}" [(ngModel)]="pDSaveModel.Days" (ngModelChange)="saveModelChanged()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let day of pD.Days" [value]="day">
            {{day}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is a screenshot of the form field out of focus

[image]

And here is the same field when focused

[image]

And here is the end result after losing focus

[image]

I have tried adding in placeholder="" to the mat-select, as well as trying different appearance options other than the default legacy. I have also tried using the floatLabel="always" property but with no luck.  Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Can you provide https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdlobdgvqok?

Comment: I am unable to provide that as I am unfamiliar how to :(

Comment: Do you have errors in the console ?

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the  tags to something like a header tag  ended up being a solution.  I then just applied a simple class to make the font-weight normal.